# does swapping an elements in an array, considered as modifying an array? LEETCODE - 287

Tags: java, arrays, cycle-sort

```
class Solution {
    public int findDuplicate(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i =0;
        while(i< arr.length){
            if(arr[i]<= arr.length  && arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]){
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[temp-1];
                arr[temp-1] = temp;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
        }
        for(int j =0; j< arr.length; j++){
            if(arr[j] !=j+1){
                return arr[j];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Leetcode - 287 - You must solve the problem without modifying the array nums and uses only constant extra space.**

Comment: Probably yes it does. Shouldn't Leetcode tell you if you fulfilled all conditions when you submit your solution? Apart from that getting around that requirement doesn't seem very hard, as you can just copy the array and work on that copy. That should be a quite small change to your code.

Comment: Of course.  The array has changed, i.e., been modified.

Comment: class Solution {
    public int findDuplicate(int[] arr) {
        int i =0;
        while(i< arr.length){
            if(arr[i] != i+1){
                if(arr[i] != arr[arr[i]-1]){
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[temp-1];
                    arr[temp-1] = temp;
                }
                else{
                    return arr[i];
                }
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }
            }
         return -1;
        }
    }  //Better Solution